# Removing FCM from web app -> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After removing all the service workers, PWA builds, and firebase-messaging-sw.js from my application, I still receive:

> StartMeetingButton.vue?eea2:71 FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you have messagingSenderId it automatically prompts firebase to use firebase/messaging package which requires service workers to be installed. Removing `messagingSenderId` from your firebase config will also remove all firebase/messaging package dependencies

````
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBRzWtEZhvkmu4mHN0eaPCCW2Av750oMzw",
  authDomain: "atmydesk-7fbc5.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://atmydesk-7fbc5.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "atmydesk-7fbc5",
  storageBucket: "atmydesk-7fbc5.appspot.com",
  // messagingSenderId: "562668644509", // REMOVE THIS LINE !!!!
  appId: "1:562668644509:web:4b103a92e9f6fd9e000c74",
  measurementId: "G-6BCMTZFPQP"
};```
````

Comment: This gives `errors.ts:101 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: Missing App configuration value: "messagingSenderId" (messaging/missing-app-config-values).`.